# Review stats page shows incorrect vote totals

Tags: bug, status-completed, up-votes, review

In the new Review Stats section of the Review page, it says I've upvoted 53 posts today.

[image]

On my [profile page](https://askubuntu.com/users/17739/root45) I have the max 40 posts voted for today.

The number listed, 53, happens to be the number of votes I have for the month. I'm not sure if that's a coincidence or not.

In any event, this seems to be a bug.

Comment: must be deleted stuff ... will clean it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a bunch of date filters around the various counts, I already filtered to the posts you looked at today, but also needed to filter the various counts.

Comment: to be deployed today